# sql server distinct row from two table on joins

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

table 1

```
id mobile uid uniqueid   time

1   9999   1232    200100   10/6/15

2   9999   1232    200100   11/5/14

3   8888   1232    200100   18/4/16

4   9999   1232    200100   07/7/15

5   9999   1232    200100   4/11/16
```

table 2

```
id   Qid    account

1    200100   123456

2    200100   123456

3    200100   123456
```

i want only non repeat data according to mobile number

i used query like

```
SELECT R.Id,R.MobileNo,R.UId,R.UniqueId,R.Time, 
ISNULL(C.account,'Not Present'), 
FROM table1 R LEFT JOIN table2 C
 ON R.uniqueId=C.QId where 
 and R.deleteStatus='Y' and C.accountNos ='123456'
```

Desire output is

```
mobile  uid    uniqueid  time    account
9999    1232    200100  4/11/16  123456
8888    1232    200100  18/4/16  123456
```

i tried every thing in sql server but cant get the desire output please help me!!!!!

Comment: Sounds like you should read about aggregation. Hint....MAX(time). FWIW,you have columns in your sample query not present in your sample data. Also, I am guessing that "time" is some sort of representation of a date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : This will give most recent data in table

```
SELECT R.Id,R.MobileNo,R.UId,R.UniqueId,MAX(R.Time),ISNULL(C.account,'Not Present'), 
FROM table1 R 
LEFT JOIN table2 C ON R.uniqueId=C.QId AND C.accountNos ='123456'   
WHERE R.deleteStatus='Y' 
GROUP BY R.Id,R.MobileNo,R.UId,R.UniqueId,ISNULL(C.account,'Not Present')
```

Comment: when i fire this query it generate following  error

Comment: Column 'Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: have tried exact script i.e i have use aggrigate function `MAX(R.Time)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
with cte as (
    SELECT 
         R.Id,
         R.MobileNo,
         R.UId,
         R.UniqueId,
         R.Time, 
         ISNULL(C.account,'Not Present'),
         Row_Number() Over(Partition by R.MobileNo order by [time] Desc) as RN
    FROM table1 R 
    LEFT JOIN table2 C
      ON R.uniqueId=C.QId 
    where 
         R.deleteStatus='Y' and C.accountNos ='123456' 
 )
   Select * from cte
   Where rn=1
```

Comment: Is there any alternate for this because i cant change the compatible mode that is 100 of my machine to 90 other things are affected

Comment: I don't think you need to downgrade your database level as the "with common table expression" and "Row_Number" are supported on 2008 and above.

Comment: this query run fines, but in output it doesn't show the data only blank column are shown

Comment: according to your example query, you specified that you only want the deleted records, R.deleteStatus='Y', which not shown in your sample data, this might affected the result. Hence, remove the Where criteria and rerun.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #TABLE1
(


ID INT, MOBILE INT, UID INT, UNIQUEID INT,  TIME DATE
)


INSERT INTO #TABLE1 VALUES(1,9999,1232,200100,'6-10-15')
INSERT INTO #TABLE1 VALUES(2,9999,1232,200100,'5-11-14')
INSERT INTO #TABLE1 VALUES(3,8888,1232,200100,'4-18-16')
INSERT INTO #TABLE1 VALUES(4,9999,1232,200100,'7-7-15')
INSERT INTO #TABLE1 VALUES(5,9999,1232,200100,'11-4-16')


SELECT * FROM #TABLE1

CREATE TABLE #B
(
ID INT,   QID INT,   ACCOUNT INT)
INSERT INTO #B VALUES

(1,200100,123456),
(2,200100,123456),
(3,200100,123456)


;WITH CTE AS
(

SELECT DISTINCT T1.MOBILE,UID,UNIQUEID,TIME,ACCOUNT, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MOBILE ORDER BY [TIME] DESC) AS RN
FROM #TABLE1 T1 JOIN #B T2 ON T1.ID=T1.ID
AND T1.UNIQUEID=T2.QID 

)
SELECT  MOBILE,UID,UNIQUEID,TIME,ACCOUNT

FROM CTE
WHERE RN=1
```